# Run Java from the command line -- unable to find main class

Tags: java, command-line, javac

I've got a folder with a handful of .java files: Triangle.java, Circle.java, Square.java, etc. The main method is in HW1.java. All the files are set to be in the package hw1.

It runs fine in NetBeans, but when I turn it in, they're going to compile it from the command line, so I'd like to make sure I can test what they're going to do.

I'm on Windows 7 and I've added Java 7 to my classpath. I go to the folder, type `javac *.java`, and .class files for all the .java files appear just fine.

Then I try to run the program. When I type `java HW1`, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HW1 (wrong name: hw1/HW1)`. When I type `java hw1/hw1`, I get `Error: Could not find or load main class hw1.HW1`. Same thing when I type `java hw1.HW1`. Same thing when I tried putting the entire folder in the classpath in-line.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You must use your `java hw1.HW1` command from the parent folder of hw1, not from hw1 itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using

```
package hw1;
```

at the top of your java file. You can remove that line if you don't need the package, in which case your

```
javac HW1.java
java HW1
```

commands should work fine. Otherwise Dici's indication to use `java hw1.HW1` from the root folder should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read this Oracle documentation.

Here is the documentation link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/

It is stated as:

*"**Error Messages on Microsoft Windows Systems**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorldApp
**If you receive this error, java cannot find your bytecode file, HelloWorldApp.class.**"*